# Screen brightness and touchpad issues on Dell XPS13 - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, xps

Last week I bought the Dell XPS 13 (L322X) ultrabook only for Ubuntu.
To make sure that I will not have any issues I installed the 12.04 LTS version instead the [Sputnik](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/3685.dell-xps-13-laptop-developer-edition-a-client-to-cloud-solution-project-sputnik.aspx) image. In Ubuntu forums, some people said that this version (12.04 LTS) had all the Sputnik features (drivers...).

Everything´s fine, I´m pretty satisfied and Ubuntu works almost ¨out the box¨ except for some issues:

1. I can´t adjust the screen brightness with the function keys (Fn + f4/f5). Actually the both keys works fine. The brightness bar appears at the left top side of the desktop, but the screen don´t respond the commands...
2. I can´t adjust the touchpad speed and sensitivity. The pointer speed it´s at the max, but still too slow...

Sorry about my English, I´m from Brazil and I´m kind rusty with the language.

Comment: Use Ubuntu 13.04 live cd and check every thing with it

Comment: Sorry, but how can i do that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Make an bootable USB/DVD of Ubuntu 13.04, When you boot with it, Use the option * Try * Ubuntu , Then you will have live session, Then you can check all your keys, stuff work or not ..!!

Comment: I know how to make the live USB, but there is any utility program for this?

Comment: if you are using Ubuntu , Download Ubuntu 13.04, Then go to dash & Search for " Start up Disk Creator", Insert USB , Then click on make Start up Disk..once done , Boot with USB & Use the option ** Try Ubuntu **

Answer (score 0):

I don't have real answers but:

I installed Linux Mint 13 on the same Dell XPS 13 with full HD screen and everything works fine.
Including the brightness and the touchpadspeed, but I think this speed is good for the laptop with normal resolution and for full HD we need double that speed, I'll try to find out how to alter this.
After some searching I found that there is a PPA for this machine:

[Will I need a PPA for my Dell XPS 13 "Sputnik" laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247695/will-i-need-a-ppa-for-my-dell-xps-13-sputnik-laptop)

In this link you can find the PPA:

http://www.calazan.com/how-to-install-the-ubuntu-12-04-sputnik-image-on-your-dell-xps-13-ultrabook/

To add the ppa: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/sputnik-kernel

Edit: I also found that the kernel since 3.9 should support everything out-of-the-box, but only the brightness controls still are not reliable.
A procedure to update the kernel can be found at http://www.upubuntu.com/

It worked for me until my last apt-get dist-upgrade, so I advise against that, it stopped my touchpad doubleclick and sidescroll.
You can try Linux Mint 13-64 bit from a Unetbootin live USB after disabling Secure boot and UEFI.
I still have Windows8 on the machine under Secure boot and UEFI but only see it after I change my bios settings.
I did some partitioning from Windows before installing Mint.
Love the machine :-)

Please let me know if you want some more information.
Good luck.
Kees , the Netherlands.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for brightness issue that helped me:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find string with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and change it to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Than reboot.

If it won't fix the issue also try to change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"
```

In the same file and reboot.